# Need to copy all fields value of specific item on table to another item in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server database snapshot:

[image]

I need to copy this selected article data to another article. Need a query in SQL to solve this issue.

Comment: pls see the attachted 'sql database snapshot'

Comment: Do you want to to copy it into another table?

Comment: From what I could understand You want to copy the fields from one table to another based on some condition

Comment: thanx Atk, i want to copy selected art_Id data to another art_id in same table. condition is that they are same in manner.

Comment: sorry guys i am new in here, i cant describe my problem rightly

Comment: i need a store procedure, where user selected two art_id which are same as per user(one art_id data already in that table). after selected second one all data replicated from first one.

Comment: i just need a idea or logic which i can proceed, no need full of code. thanx

Comment: So you need a VIEW maybe?

Comment: Thanx, i guess so CodeSlave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you wan the IEDetails table to have the values for art_id = 7545 copied with a different art_id value while still retaining the original values?  With the data shown, I am going to assume that the Id column is defined as an IDENTITY column

If so then this should work for you:

```
DECLARE @new_art_id INT
DECLARE @old_art_id INT
SET @old_art_id = 7545
SET @new_art_id = 8000

INSERT IEDetails (art_id, ProcessId, SrlNo)
SELECT @new_art_id, ProcessId, SrlId
FROM IEDetails
WHERE art_id = @old_art_id
```

You could change where you get the values for `@old_art_id` and `@new_art_id` by using a different query than the `SET` statements.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.I am so glad. You save my lot of time. That's what i am looking. Same way as you did i completed for IE_Master table also.

Comment: Also thanks all for helping me here, take your time to posted here.